# What is this short story about someone who gets "projected" to another planet?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember the name and author of a short story about a scientist whose consciousness is projected onto another planet.

I read it 10 years ago or so on a PDF that stated the author and title, but didn't mention the compilation or magazine it came from.

I can't remember the year of publication either.

This was definitely the longest "short" story I've read in my life. It was at least 20 pages.

It started with the protagonist, who was visiting an observatory or some place where they study space.

He was a scientist, I think, or someone just visiting.

For some reason, he trips and falls inside a telescope or similar device, and he is stuck, maybe hanging upside down, and his head is in the way of a powerful ray.

The machine starts working and shoots the ray, causing either a hallucination or the "projection" of his consciousness to another planet.

This is where the story begins.

I don't remember if he ever came back.

He wakes up on another planet, where there is something or someone being held captive.

Maybe it was a person, or even a computer.

During the story, for some reason, he wants to walk through a bridge, but there are beings that could attack him, so he's afraid, and maybe even fights them somehow.

Those beings are, I think, big birds or humanoid birds.

That's everything I can remember.

Comment: I just noticed that this has been asked about before and has an accepted answer. Per site policy I will close your question as a duplicate. There's no stigma attached to this kind of closure, it just helps keep the site tidy. An answer to this old question refers to the shorter version you mentioned in a comment to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're describing *[Midsummer Century](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?21819)* by James Blish.

It has the elements of the story kicking off with the scientist falling into the focus of a telescope (a "radio telescope of a radically new design", and the humanoid or at least intelligent birds.

His new radio telescope doesn't work, so he turns it up to full power and starts climbing around in the framework to figure out why. Then

> Settling one sneakered foot into what appeared to be a perfectly secure angle between one girder and another, he slipped and fell headlong down the inside of the tube....In fact, he never hit bottom at all.

His mind ends up sharing the "mind" of a computer or cyborg named Qvant, then a future human primitive tribesman. There are intelligent avian adversaries called Birds.

> Another rush of feathers and disturbed air, and its place was taken by a scarlet and gold effigy nearly as tall as he was...a combination which suggested both the eagle and the owl...

Differences:

- He wakes up in the far future, not another planet.
- It's quite a bit longer than 20 pages. In the paperback I have it's about 90 pages.
- A skim of the story did not turn up the bridge thing, but I could easily have missed it.

Comment: That is the story, thank you! The book I found mentions that it was published as a shorter version too in "Fantasy and Science Fiction" magazine, in April 1972. I thought I was misremembering reading 100 pages. I read that or the shorter version. Thank you again!

Comment: @Arealuser you're most welcome, and welcome to sf stack exchange!